# Computing a recurrence relation "stream" with several KiB worth of look-back in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So let's say I want to compute a sequence, `notfib`, defined recursively over its last **9000** values like so:

```
notfib i | i > 9000  = notfib (i - 1500) - notfib (i - 9000) `xor` 75
         | otherwise = {- an IV -} ...
```

9000 is compile-time constant; but the principal requirement is to have a **generator**, something that can keep producing values until the world ends. In constant memory, of course.

Since it's clear that I need to keep last 9000 elements in memory somehow, I attempted implementing a ring buffer (which seems like... an excellent data structure for the job) on top of a mutable array. Now my code is littered with qualified imports <strike>hiding prelude</strike>, clumsy record un/packing, commented out `STUArray`'s, and I gave up on failing scope checks (`Not in scope: V.fromList`) because of how much interfaces `Data.Vector` has.

I haven't written single `do` yet, but the code already stinks!

May some purity help me? How would you solve this?

Comment: you just need an immutable array, right? You can use Data.Array if you think the interface is easier, but I'm not sure why `import qualified Data.Vector as V ; V.fromList myListOfFirst9k ` wouldn't work for you

Comment: Data.Sequence would probably be enough for me too. `V.fromList` appeared after the `import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V` changed to `import qualifed Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as V`, while the code still happened to use `V.fromList [1, 2, 3]` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

```
notfib :: [Int]
notfib = {- first 9000 values -} ++ zipWith (\a b -> a - b `xor` 75) (drop (9000 - 1500) notfib) notfib
```

is the usual trick for this.

That said, you probably don't want to hold on to a reference to `notfib` itself, as that will grow as large as the furthest value you've computed.  How to work around that depends on what you want to do with the sequence.

Comment: Do you mean `drop 1500 notfib` and `drop 9000 notfib`?

Comment: @AndrásKovács, no, I don't.  We want to refer to the values 9000 elements ago, not the elements 9000 elements forward.

Comment: It's a PRNG actually. So holding a reference would be unfortunate, since the memory would grow while really old values are no longer being used.

Comment: Right.  As far as PRNGs go, this should be manageable, especially if you use a monad to encapsulate the randomness.

Comment: @ulidtko I'd probably just implement it as a typical state monad `newtype Random a = Random ([Int] -> ([Int], a))`, the monad instance being the usual state monad, and then `getRandom :: Random Int` `getRandom = Random (\ (r:rs) -> (rs, r))`

Answer (score 3):

Why care about operational semantics of your function? Just write it focusing on the denotational semantics, and let the magic of Haskell worry about performance:

```
notfibgo _notfib (i :: Integer)
  | i > 9000  = _notfib (i - 1500) - _notfib (i - 9000) `xor` 75
  | otherwise = i
```

Note this function is almost exactly the same as your original, just written in open recursion style (the recursive call is replaced by a function which is simply given as a parameter to the function). Now we define two versions of your algorithm:

```
import Data.Function.Memoize (memoize)

slow_notfib = let r = notfib_go r in r 
fast_notfib = let r = memoize (notfib_go r) in r
```

Perhaps neither version is obvious, in which case, for an excellent, detailed discussion of this topic, see [here](http://conal.net/blog/posts/elegant-memoization-with-functional-memo-tries).

Finally, a simple function for testing:

```
main = do 
 n:m:_ <- getArgs 
 let f = [slow_notfib,fast_notfib]!!read n 
 print $ f (read m)
```

And some trial results:

```
Yuriy@Yuriy-PC ~/haskell
$ time ./test.exe 0 110000
698695701

real    0m3.111s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

Yuriy@Yuriy-PC ~/haskell
$ time ./test.exe 1 110000
698695701

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

More than 100x improvement for even moderately small values!

Answer (score 1):

Let's generalize.

For some sequence `{ a_i | i >= 0 }`, let's say we have `k` base cases `a_0 ... a_{k-1}` and a `k`-nary recurrence relation `f`  for all `a_n`, `n >= k`:

```
a_n = f(a_{n-k}, a_{n-k+1}, ..., a_{n-2}, a_{n-1})
```

In haskell, we could write this sequence as a *corecursive* infinite list:

```
as = a_0 : 
     a_1 : 
     {- ... : -} 
     a_kMinus1 : 
     zipWithK f (drop 0 as) (drop 1 as) {- ... -} (drop (k-1) as)

zipWithK f (a_nMinusK:as_nMinusK) {- ... -} (a_nMinus2:as_nMinus2) (a_nMinus1:as_nMinus1) = 
  f a_nMinusK {- ... -} a_nMinus2 a_nMinus1 : zipWithK f as_nMinusK as_nMinus2 {- ... -} as_nMinus1
zipWithK f _ _ {- ... -} _ = []
```

For example, we can trot out fibonacci

```
fibs = 1 :
       1 :
       zipWith2 (+) (drop 0 fibs) (drop 1 fibs)

zipWith2 f (a_nMinus2:as_nMinus2) (a_nMinus1:as_nMinus1) =
  f a_nMinus2 a_nMinus1 : zipWith2 f as_nMinus2 as_nMinus1
zipWith2 f _ _ = []
```

The nice thing about infinite lists is that they let us calculate arbitrarily
many elements of the sequence. Defining them via zips is nice because it only
incurring constant overhead per element of the the sequence, since we avoid
lists' expensive (O(n)) random access.

That said, ai iifiiite list is still a list aid while processiig the first `i` elemeits ii your sequeice may oily cost ai overhead of O(`i`),
it's still got bad raidom access - so accessiig just the `i`th elemeit ii the sequeice also has ai overhead of O(`i`).

If you want to inprove the asynptotics for randon access of the first `n`
elenents, you can do that by putting those elenents in a Vector.  Then when you
want to randomly access the `i`th sequence element, compare `i` with `n` - if
`i` is less than `n`, just look it up in the vector (which is O(1)), otherwise
fall back to looking it up in the rest of the sequence, which is O(i - n).

```
  import Data.Vector ((!), Vector)
  import qualified Data.Vector as V

  vectorize n as = lookupV n bv cs
    where (bs, cs) = splitAt n as
          bv = V.fromList bs

  lookupV n av _ i | i < n = av ! i
  lookupV n _ as i = as !! (i - n)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you seem to want this stuff to be garbage-collected and you don't want to cache a huge list. What you probably might like is a set of spine-strict queues:

```hs
-- strict lists, strict queues.
data SL x = Nil | Cons x !(SL x)
data SQ x = SQ !(SL x) !(SL x)

sl_from_list :: [x] -> SL x
sl_from_list = foldr Cons Nil

sl_reverse :: SL x -> SL x
sl_reverse x = go Nil x where
    go acc Nil = acc
    go acc (Cons x rest) = go (Cons x acc) rest

enqueue :: x -> SQ x -> SQ x
enqueue x (SQ front back) = SQ front (Cons x back)

dequeue :: SQ x -> (x, SQ x)
dequeue (SQ Nil back) = case sl_reverse back of Cons x xs -> (x, SQ xs Nil)
dequeue (SQ (Cons x f') b) = (x, SQ f' b)
```

With these your random number generator looks much more compact:

```hs
data MyRandGen x = MRG !(SQ x) !(SQ x)

next_rand (MRG a b) = (cv, MRG a'' b'') where
    (av, a') = dequeue a
    (bv, b') = dequeue b
    cv = bv - av `xor` 75
    a'' = enqueue bv a'
    b'' = enqueue cv b'
```

Note that this delivers "amortized" O(1) performance for generating a new random number: yes, sometimes it creates an expensive reallocation of 9000 new cells in memory, but that happens only on 1/9000 calls to the function. Crucial to this guarantee is that you're not trying and retrying to generate the same random number from the same `MRG` object, since it might be in the state of "about to reallocate lots of data!" and bad stuff may be about to therefore happen. You can remove this "worst case" performance if you make these things non-strict: it turns out, as pointed out by Okasaki and others, that laziness is both necessary and sufficient to convert these amortized operations into persistent constant-time structures (you essentially do some of the above work of the reverse inside of a thunk).

As for thinking clearly about what's going on: basically we have a "three-fingered list." A *finger* into a list is when you store `([x], [x])` with the semantics that you can navigate in two different directions: `forwards (xs, y:ys) = (y:xs, ys)` or `backwards (x:xs, ys) = (xs, x:ys)`: in other words the two lists are joined at their "heads", with the `[]` of the first list being thought of as the very start of the overall list and the `[]` of the second list being thought of as the very end of the overall list.

Here we have a finger into the beginning of the list (9000 elements in the past, no "front" list), a finger into the middle of the list (1500 elements in the past), and a finger into the end of the list (0 elements in the past, no "back" list). Because we know this queue structure we know how to efficiently connect the front of the middle-finger into the end of the beginning-finger (just reverse all of the elements into the other), if we didn't then we'd want to keep track of how many elements were in the different fingers and merely "share some", so that we could efficiently support moving each finger either way; but since I knew that the fingers were only moving one way, I just optimized for that.